# Filter.aspx and GetDistinctValues

Tags: 2010, column, filter

We found an issue, that filters on columns are stop working. Error message is:

> Cannot show the value of the filter. The field may not be filterable,
>   or the number of items returned exceeds the list view threshold
>   enforced by the administrator

The issue can be resolved after saving "broken" column in the user interface. Even with no changes.

After some research - reason of this behavior was page filter.aspx page and GetDistinctValues function at this page. When column was in "broken" state function return only name of the column. After saving (through the UI) GetDistinctValues return html markup of the filter values (select, option and etc.) Decompiling and debugging filter.aspx shows that different result produce RenderAsHtml of the List, executing SPQueries (in ViewXml) which differ only with

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='myColumnName'/>
</ViewFields>
```

Type of column - multiuser.

I need to fix this issue but through standard features updating, or PowerShell script. Simple change and Update() of "broken" field doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No, we lost hope