# Threshold error message upon opening filter drop-down on indexed column already filtered by *one* value

Tags: 2016, filter, list-view-threshold

I have a list with 7000+ items on a SP 2016 environment that has the default threshold of 5000 items. I created a view filtered on 'ID is less than 2500'. This view contains 5 columns (all indexed), has no sorting, grouping, or totals, and is paged in batches of 30. The view displays just fine.

### Issue: error message on returning to filter drop-down

When I pull down the column head drop-down menu, select *one* filter value, close the drop-down, the filtering is applied correctly.
However, when I return to that drop-down, the following error alert appears.

> Cannot show the value of the filter. The field may not be filterable, or the number of items returned exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator.

Inspecting in F12, I found the offending request is:

```
https://[sitecollection]/[web]/_layouts/15/filter.aspx?ListId=[ListId]&FieldInternalName=[fieldname]&ViewId=[ViewId]&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1&FilterField1=[fieldname]&FilterValue1=abc
```

When more than one value have been selected previously, the request becomes (note the plural on FilterField**s**1 and FilterValue**s**):

```
https://[sitecollection]/[web]/_layouts/15/filter.aspx?ListId=[ListId]&FieldInternalName=[fieldname]&ViewId=[ViewId]&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1&FilterFields1=[fieldname]&FilterValues1=abc%3B%23def
```

Related issue: [Filter.aspx and GetDistinctValues](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93953/filter-aspx-and-getdistinctvalues)

#### Notes:

- After I click OK to get rid of the error message, the filter drop-down only displays 'Clear Filters on [this column]', not the actual filter values.
- This only happens when I select one filter value from the drop-down and only on indexed columns

A second, possibly related issue is the following:
When I filter out one value on an indexed column, then try to filter one value in another column (whether or not indexed), the second filtering is not done and an HTTP 601 error appears on the POST call to inplview.aspx. The second filtering only gets done after I unfilter the first column.

Any ideas on why this happens or better still, how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe doing an 'Export to Excel' would help - what happens when you filter the data in Excel?  Does it exceed the item limit?

Comment: Hi, I can export my view to Excel and filter it any way I want there. The view has 2500 items and therefor does not exceed the threshold, which is set to 5000.

Comment: Have a read through this post, perhaps it will help: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168341/list-view-threshold-shows-as-exceeded-even-when-it-is-not.  Also, when you click on this link, look at the right side of the page, see the section titled 'Related', these a similar kinds of posts so would likely be worthwhile reading as part of your troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks, I already read these (and many other) posts. I further investigated and refined my post.